# Middle of monitor is being displayed on the side instead on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 17.10

Hey guys I just decided to install ubuntu on my windows machine and I am having a bit of a display issue that you can see in the image below. There is a line in the middle of the screen that is distorted and it is being displayed on the side of the monitor instead. You can see the problem on the left side of my monitor. Sorry about the photo instead of screenshot since a screenshot doesn't capture the problem. Does anyone know of a solution?

[image]

Some perhaps relevant information. I have a 144hz 1440p as my main monitor as well as an ultrawide monitor as my secondary. The problem exists on the main one. I am using a amd r9 390 gpu.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to see what you mean in that photo.  Do you mean the narrow strip along the very left of the monitor?

Comment: Yea so there's a strip on the left of the monitor that basically displays what should be in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @thomasrutter Yeah, I think they mean that that line on the very left is a copy of a vertical line in the middle (see how the black section in the middle corresponds to the terminal window's black section and the white sections correspond to the browser's white sections under the terminal window).

Comment: After upgrading to 17.10 I had some display issues, so I did dconf reset -f / , which resets gnome, and everthing was fine.

Comment: I just tried the dconf command and it hasn't helped. I tried installing the amd drivers and my computer just wouldn't boot until I removed it.