# Graphical Glitch, strip of about 5 pixels from the middle of the screen are being drawn on the far right edge

Tags: graphics, amd-graphics

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.2 and these are my graphics settings:

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 21 [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 resolution=2560,1440
       resources: irq:79 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe300000-fe3fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

I'm having the exact same problem as this question here: [Middle of monitor is being displayed on the side instead on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001165/middle-of-monitor-is-being-displayed-on-the-side-instead-on-ubuntu-17-10) Unfortunately that question is as yet unanswered. I'm re-asking because that was for Ubuntu 17, and I'm now on 22.

Basically there is a strip of about 5 pixels wide from the top to the bottom of the screen, roughly in the middle, which is being drawn on the rightmost edge of the screen. When I move my mouse through the area I can see my mouse on the right edge of the screen.

Edit: It just happend again, this time though the missing strip is on the left side of the screen. The PC didn't go into sleep mode, but I turned the monitor off for a few minutes and then turned it back on. After turning it on the problem occured.

What could be causing this and how could I fix it?

Here's some screenshots of the problem:

pixels missing from the middle of the screen:
[image]

The missing pixels on the right side of the screen:
[image: missing]

pixels missing from the middle of the screen:
[image: mi]

The missing pixels on the right side of the screen:
[image]

Comment: Not sure, but does that happen if you switch your session from wayland to X11/Xorg? (You can switch the session in the login screen - cog right bottom)

Comment: Could you add a photo? Did you try switching with Xorg instead of Wayland (or vice versa)? Is your system updated? Nothing that could be related on `journalctl -xe`? Also happen with other screen on mirror?

Comment: Could you also add screenshot beside camera photo?

Comment: At soon as I see it happen again I'll get a photo. It's no happening right now however. It pops up every once in a while. I never purposely switch between wayland and X11. I'll try that and see if it can cause it.

Comment: @user.dz ok, I've finally managed to snag some screenshots. I've noticed it tends to happen whenever it returns from sleep mode. It also fixes itself with a restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a hardware problem with my monitor. Turning the monitor off and on again a few times works as a workaround.

The solution is not owning a cheapshit monitor.